# No Wifi connection on HP elitebook 8570w with Intel Ultimate -N 6300

Tags: networking, drivers, hp, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

04 next to windows 7 and my wifi is not working.
I have an HP Elitebook 8570w with an Intel Cooperation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 3e) wifi card that works fine on windows 7. The connection symbol in the menu bar says "Wifi Networks device not ready"

It might be nothing, but i noticed that the hardware wifi switch on my keyboard still works, altho the light keeps burning red. (I verified it works by checking with rfkill list)

lshw -c Network gives me

```
    t:5040(size=32)
  *-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 3e
   serial: 24:77:03:b2:f9:d4
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-31-    generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:33 memory:d9100000-d9101fff
```

At first i thought it was a rfkill issue, but rfkill list shows no sign of problems

```
    gijs@gijs-HP-EliteBook-8570w:~$ rfkill list
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
    1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

If i enter dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlan 
I get the following as an output. I dont realy where to look fore. This are the first lines:

```
    [   16.599881] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
    [   16.976938] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode failed with error -2
    [   16.992926] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-6000-5.ucode failed with error -2
    [   17.052359] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: loaded firmware version 9.221.4.1 build 25532 op_mode iwldvm
    [   18.051712] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
    [   18.051715] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
    [   18.051716] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
    [   18.051718] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN, REV=0x74
    [   18.051766] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
    [   18.171355] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
    [   32.395035] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
    [   32.395165] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
    [   32.401812] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
    [   32.401899] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
    [   32.436644] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting     0x82000000.
```

I have been searching on the web for days, installed different versions of Ubuntu, ran all upgrades and updates but nothing works. Please help me out.

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlan` ?

Comment: I edited the output in my question. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

We see the dreaded firmware error in your log:

> Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting

Let's install the latest firmware and see if it helps:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and tell us if you connect.

Comment: nope doesnt work :p

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by buying a seperated hardware dongel found here

[https://www.amazon.com/Edimax-EW-7811Un-150Mbps-Raspberry-Supports/dp/B003MTTJOY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY)

This device has the most standard network car available and almost works on every device, from Lego Mindstorm to Rasbery Pi 
My professor told me I would have to reprogram a part of the Kernel that is responsible for this, and since i am kinda new to Ubuntu i dont wanna do that. This works fine, i'm happy